# How to Double Click Toggle visibility of React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Currently have a popup component showing up double click using the `onDoubleClick()` handler.But I'd like to close that popup on double click of the popup component  but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I have been trying, the thought process was to just to set toggleModal to false and it should work.

```
const [selectedImageId, setSelectedImageId] = useState(-1);
const [toggleModal, setToggleModal] = useState(false);

const handleModalPopupOnClick = (id) => {
    setSelectedImageId(id);
    setToggleModal(true);
};

return (
      <div>
         {toggleModal && <PopupModal onDoubleClick={setToggleModal(false)}/>}
          <div onDoubleClick{()=> handleModalPopupOnClick(image.id)>Open Popup</div>
      </div>
     

)
```

Any ideas? Thank you for any suggestions or guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
{toggleModal && <PopupModal onDoubleClick={setToggleModal(false)}/>}
```

Is immediately calling `setToggleModal` with an argument of false when the component is rendered, and I believe `undefined` becomes the value of `onDoubleClick`. (Not 100% on if `setState` has a return value or not)

To fix your problem you should provided this as a prop:

```
{toggleModal && <PopupModal onDoubleClick={() => setToggleModal(false)}/>}
```

This is providing a function definition rather than calling the function.

Comment: That was it right there. For some reason I didn't realize that it was passing it down as a prop and not an inline function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `PopupModal` is your custom component, so it doesn't provide `onDoubleClick` event.

`onDoubleClick` in this line:

```
{toggleModal && <PopupModal onDoubleClick={setToggleModal(false)}/>}
```

is just a prop.
So you must call `props.onDoubleClick` in the handler of `onDoubleClick` event inside the `PopupModal`.